# Parse Push Notifications: Another Error Occurred

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using parse.com and my app is in production mode. and I have an issue with push notifications for IOS.

most of the times it works fine but sometimes it show "Another Error Occurred" in push notification explorer with the status sent. But users not getting push notification as they were supposed to get.

So how can I trace what is the reason behind and how can I fix this?

it's not certificate related issue as I have already changed my certificate on parse.com, and if it was certificate issue it should occurred each time.

does anyone have any idea how to fix this?